# AS 2.3 update breaking my gradle build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.3, my gradle simply started complaining about some "ghost" libraries I don't have.
I've downgraded my target and build sdk versions due to a prod. bug.

[image]

What my gradle looks like:

```
compile files('libs/apptimize-android-2.12.4.jar')


    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.4.1'
    //compile 'com.apptimize:apptimize-android:2.12.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.4.1'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'
//    compile 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.0'
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.0.4'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.2'
```

I've run `./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile` but I don't understand what's going on here:

```
No configurations
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.4.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.2.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3 -> 2.3.1
+--- org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6
|    \--- org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.4.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2
|    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12
+--- id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6
+--- com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.0.4
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1 -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.7.0
+--- com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 25.0.0
|    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
\--- io.card:android-sdk:5.4.2
```

I don't have any 25.0.0 version anywhere, why is this happening ?
Where is this animated-vector-drawable coming from ?
I've already invalidated the cache, cleaned and rebuilt but the error keeps showing up.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a mix of the facebook, Urban Airship and photoview issues. Actually downgrading them resolved the issue.